# How in React MUI Tooltip add multiple text as label and sublabel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm adding a MaterialUI Tooltip to my React app and I need to have two text lines.
One will be treated as the title main text the other one as a sublabel.

Here in the screenshot, you can see where I stuck

[image: ![image of the issue]

The goal is to have it all in one card as

```
The label should read: Self-assessment opened: [n]

Sub-label: Click to drill down
```

An example from the Figma I have which shows how the card should look

[image: figma example]

I'm new to MUI and not sure how I should do it and this is the code I have so far

```
import { Box, Popper, Tooltip } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/styles';
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';

// Use styles from src/analytics/components/TooltipCard/TooltipCard.js to make it look the same
const TooltipCardPopper = styled(Popper)(({ theme }) => ({
  '& > div': {
    ...theme.typography.caption,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[7],
    borderRadius: '5px',
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(1.2),
    paddingRight: theme.spacing(1.2),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(0.5),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(0.5),
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: theme.palette.grey[300],
  },
}));

const calculateTotals = ({ data }) =>
  data?.reduce(function (accumulator, item) {
    return accumulator + item.total;
  }, 0);

const CenteredMetricToolTip = ({ position, data }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const intl = useIntl();
  const show = !!position;

  const total = calculateTotals({ data });

  return (
    <Tooltip
      open={show}
      disableFocusListener
      disableHoverListener
      disableTouchListener
      disableInteractive
      title={intl.formatMessage({ defaultMessage: 'Click to drill down' })}
      PopperComponent={TooltipCardPopper}
      TransitionProps={{ timeout: 0 }} // timeout more than 0 => transition => causes re-positioning and blinking
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          position: 'absolute',
          display: show ? 'block' : 'hide',
          left: `${position?.x ?? 0}px`,
          top: `${position?.y ?? 0}px`,
        }}
      >
        {intl.formatMessage(
          { defaultMessage: ' Self-assessment opened: {total}' },
          { total },
        )}
      </Box>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default CenteredMetricToolTip;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change `title` property value from  `title={intl.formatMessage({ defaultMessage: 'Click to drill down' })}` to

```
 title={
       <div>
         <div>{intl.formatMessage({ defaultMessage:"Self-assessment opened: [n]" })}<div>
         <div>{intl.formatMessage({ defaultMessage:"Click to drill down"})}</div>
       <div> 
 }
```

on `Tooltip` Component

Comment: How should make it work without the children of the tooltip as now I have both boxes and if I remove the inside of the tooltip is failing as ref is not defined

Comment: You should give that chart component inside children tooltip. When that chart hovers then it will show tooltip of that

Comment: I cannot do that as the text is an SVG inside the chart component and the other slices of the pie chart have Nivo inbuild labels so I cannot do that on the entire component

Comment: then try adding `<></>` inside tooltip children